# Trying to create a batch file that opens CMD in working directory and calls a command to see who is logged into servers

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

what I know works;

open cmd in working directory: `cmd /k`

command to return logged in users: `for /f %s in (servers.txt) do (echo %s & qwinsta /server:%s )`
as servers.txt is a list of servers

I can't get this to work together; and i'd like to have it print to a text file when finished.

Comment: What do you mean by `I can't get this to work together`? What output do you get when you run that code?

Comment: & was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `FOR` in a batch file, you have to double-up the `%` on the `FOR` variables.

```
for /f %%s in (servers.txt) do (echo %%s & qwinsta /server:%%s )
```

Answer (score 1):

That will work if you're running it from a command prompt but if you you want to run it from a batch file, you have to double your %%'s on your for variables. Here is how you do it writing to a file from a batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
(for /f %%s in (servers.txt) do (echo %%s & qwinsta /server:%%s ))>output.txt
type output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!! if I could upvote you and aphoria I would... I haven't had too much time today to look into it but the new issue is the output file. when I now run the batch file the server names no longer appear on the output file. i'll see if I can figure it out after lunch but figured i'd give you all a status update. thanks again